# Display Filters on columns exported into Excel from RDLC report

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, reporting, rdlc

I want to display Filters on some (or may be all) the columns in my excel file that is exported from RDLC report. I generate many files per day, and every time I generate the file, I have to open the excel file, select all columns and then apply filter on them. Is there any way in RDLC reporting, the filter may be applied automatically when the data is exported to excel?

Comment: Adding a filter on the column or appyling the filter on the data already?

Comment: Applying Filters on the columns, like we can do in Excel. Have Filter dropdown appear on each column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to your answer, have a look here [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/11fc0847-da07-4e18-90ee-3ba98bfc5c5c/create-dynamic-dropdown-list-when-we-export-data-to-excel-using-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices). In the current version of SSRS it is not possible to export an excel with added filters. I have worked with rdlc and rdl formats quite alot and ssrs is highly lacking when it comes to advanced formatting and additional features like filters. You may want to look at something like [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) if you have the requirement of creating advanced documents. Hope it helps

Comment: The best you may be able to acheive is to add a dropdown filter on your reportviewer which can filter the data for you already. Then when you export you get filtered data.